# How to collect report from copy artifact plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins to build complicated project from different sources. Last build copy artifact from previous builds and create product. I want to get report what exactly were copied(build name, build number, changelog of source build, etc)
Final build have no upstreams and started manualy or by commit into own git repo.

I think groovy postbuild step can help me. But i do not understand how to get access to CopyArtifactPlugin Property.

Comment: I'm not sure that the Copy Artifact plugin records this information during a build, other than in the console output.

Answer (score 0):

I find this workaround by parsing build log.

[You can see gist here](https://gist.github.com/Arbuzov/061ef138f4b10b755f31001f461de55e)